# How to rotate an image smoothly in clockwise in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile

im trying to rotate an image in clockwise (seconds) with smooth animation , this my current code :

```
  Transform.rotate(
          angle: _dateTime.second * 6 * pi / 180,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/Clocks/FirstClock/secondhand.png',
          ),
        ),
```

I've tried animation builder and rotation transition but I can't apply the seconds angle to the animation its always inaccurate

Comment: Why are you using a quantized value with one-second resolution to decide your position?  You should get something with millisecond resolution to do the math, so that you get a new result for every animation frame.

Comment: you want to animate one time or continuously?

Comment: i want to animate continuously , based on the current time

Answer (score 0):

**I'm Trying to Solve your Problem :**

**Use Transform.rotate For Rotate image smoothly in clockwise:**

```
Transform.rotate(
      angle: _angleInRadians,
      child: Image.asset('assets/abc.jpg'),
    );
```

**Code:**

```
class RotateImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RotateImageState createState() => _RotateImageState();
}

class _RotateImageState extends State<RotateImage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Ticker _ticker;
  double _angleInRadians = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _ticker = this.createTicker((_) => setState(() {
      _angleInRadians += 0.01;
    }))
      ..start();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _ticker.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: _angleInRadians,
      child: Image.asset('assets/abc.jpg'),
    );
  }
}
```

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fXO2aPgL-SUC7T6F9JTtYyysAI3fLdgy/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: but this will only rotate randomly , im rotating the image based on the time ( seconds ) , like the if the time is 12:56:30 , the image should be pointing at that second angle

Comment: have you run this code?

Comment: this is working fine as you want

Comment: nope , its rotating yes , but its inaccurate , its just rotating randomly

Comment: okay i will update my answer later

Answer (score 0):

First make a statefulwidget
It takes two parameters the image provider and the duration. Pass the parameterss in the constructor.

In the state class put a animatedController

```
late AnimationController _controller;
```

Then in the initState initialize the controller.

```
_controller = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 
widget.duration.toInt()),
)..repeat();
```

Then inside your build method put

```
RotationTransition(
    turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 
    1.0).animate(_controller),
    child: Image(
    image: widget.imageProvider,
  ),
),
```

You can finally call the dispose method
To dispose the controller

Comment: this is the same answer as below , this will rotate smoothly but its inaccurate , its not rotating based on the current time